# Is there any way to detect the finger touch on phone's fingerprint?

Tags: java, android

```
     `// Check whether at least one fingerprint is registered
                       if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
                           textView.setText("Register at least one fingerprint in Settings");
                       }else{
                           // Checks whether lock screen security is enabled or not
                           if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {
                               textView.setText("Lock screen security not enabled in Settings");
                           }else{
                               generateKey();
          initCipher();
         }
    protected void generateKey() {
           try {
               keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }


           KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
           try {
               keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
           } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
           }


           try {
               keyStore.load(null);
               keyGenerator.init(new
                       KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                       KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                               KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                       .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                       .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                       .setEncryptionPaddings(
                               KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                       .build());
               keyGenerator.generateKey();
           } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
                   InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                   | CertificateException | IOException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
           }
       }

public boolean cipherInit() {
       try {
           cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/" + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
       }


       try {
           keyStore.load(null);
           SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                   null);
           cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
           return true;
       } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
           return false;
       } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
       }
   }
`
```

I get the authentication code,where it check the previous fingerprint key is availlable or not using fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints() this method. But i need only the detection of touch on fingerprint.When any user touch, go to next activity. I actually want to check that the fingerprint sensor is working or not. (without authentication check) Is there any solution?

I already tried it. But it is not my solution.

Comment: You might want to add some code example to your question. The sourcode from the link you provided is not available without authentication.

Comment: I add my authentication code. But this is not the exact what i need. I need only detection of finger touch without any authentication.

Comment: Did you try using the `authenticate` method and its `callback` parameter? Afaik `enrolled fingerprints` seem to refer to system registered fingerprints, which is not what you are looking for. -- Also the whole `keystore` code seems to be unrelated to your question.

Comment: yes. i know about only the authentication code. but what is the solution of my question?? is there any way or method to detect touch?

Comment: The question would be what do you define as `touch`. There are few help codes defined that should be delivered to the callback, e.g.: `FINGERPRINT_ACQUIRED_PARTIAL`. I assume you have to test it out, to see what callback gets invoked. Depending on that you should be able to tell whether the sensor is working or not. Even a call to `onAuthenticationFailed` should tell you that the sensor is working.

Comment: But  without previous enrolled fingerprints in phone  settings,this code does not work in  
 this line. cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key); . If i need previous enrolled fingerprint, then it's actually not, what i need.

Comment: In that case you probably can not use the `Fingerprint API`. You will have to look for a `SDK` that allows you to use the hardware directly.

Comment: ok . got it. I think it is possible only system application  of android. @second